# Hay was Royi exonerated in that last little kerfuffel?

Tags: discussion

So Royi was identified by the powers that be (and their bots) to be sock-puppeting with two or three other accounts.  I see that this discussion (started by Overlord) was removed.  I would like the mods to confirm that such action against Royi was a mistake or not.  I need to feel confident that someone is not just wasting my time.

So now I just figgered out that it's Overlord that's in the doghouse.  Is that related to this?  Is the sock-puppetry that was first blamed on Royi now blamed on Overlord?

What's going on here?

Comment: I would also like some transparency on this.

Comment: Robert, Feel free to contact me personally, I will tell you what I did wrong. No need to be offensive.

Comment: @Royi I wanna hear it from the mods.  And I wanna know why the previous thread that Overlord started was removed.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, If you contact me privately I will share with you exactly what I was suspended for as written to me by the moderators. If you're so interested, I am willing to reveal it to you, yet privately.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to be as minimal as possible until I learn it is safe to speak further.

I was suspended for 30 days on DSP.SE for my Meta posts, and 30 days network-wide for pinging several DSP.SE users about it on other networks.

Royi: my e-mail is fully protected by the First Amendment. Yet your now-deleted comment, whose screenshot I have, itches on defamation.

RBJ: browsing history exists, and you have 10k+ rep.

Royi's offer to share privately is subject to digital manipulation. Whoever wants, can e-mail me (see my [GH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr1lQ.png)), anonymously or not - I'll respond to anyone, the title can be "dsp" and body blank.

I'm a forgiving and understanding person, and gave benefit of doubt all the way - my posts were never about Royi. Despite what I'll say next, and what I've suffered to his actions, it's still the case that this isn't about Royi. My good faith was shattered with Royi's answer and comments here, saying whatever he's said, instead of apologizing.

Comment: Well, welcome back.  I dunno diddly shit.  Dunno if I wanna learn diddly.

Answer (score -3):

To answer your question, I am not aware of a link between my case to current suspension of @[OverLordGoldDragon](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/50076/overlordgolddragon).

But I want to make something clear.
The way the system work is not by embracing the level of confidence of civil court or criminal court.
Rules are enforced in manner which allows **handling a community at scale** with maximum reasonability.
Yet the priority is scale and then being right / making justice.

One need to accept this when participating in SE.
It is not a democratic space. At least not in its standards to decide right and wrong. There are rules, there are, mostly algorithm driven, way to monitor them and there are suspension policies.
Since it is like that, I find it is reasonable to keep things in private as opposed to justice system.

For the sake of transparency, Anyone who is interested to know what I was suspended for may contact me privately.
I will share the exact screen shot of the message of the moderators.
If one is interested to hear my side, I can share that as well, in private.
This public space is not adequate to a game of accusations and then trying disproving them. It is said that by the time a lie circles the world twice the truth barely gets its ties tied.
So conspiration and accusation will always have larger crowd.

I don't see the point of making it in public as the process is not built like court or something like that. It is part of the "game".

I intend to keep being active member in SE.
For me, it is all about gaining and sharing knowledge.